# Using puppeteer on an actual API

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm sorry for the long question, I'm a newbie at node but I have made a CRUD API before with authentication and everything, I just need to understand how to integrate puppeteer to the API, so let me begin:

This is my project structure:

1. puppeteer-api

   - controllers - puppeteer.controller.js
   - routes - puppeteer.routes.js
   - index.js

This is my index.js file:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express = require('express');
const booking = require('./routes/puppeteer.routes')

const app = express();

app.use('/booking', booking);

let port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on https://localhost:8080/');
});
```

puppeteer.routes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const puppeteer_controller = require('../controllers/puppeteer.controller');

router.get('/', puppeteer_controller.get_booking);

module.exports = router;
```

puppeteer.controller.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

exports.get_booking = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json = (async function main() {
    try {

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.goto('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.es-ar.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAyIAQGYASy4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgM&lang=es-ar&sid=bc11c3e819d105b3c501d0c7a501c718&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.es-ar.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAyIAQGYASy4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgM%3Bsid%3Dbc11c3e819d105b3c501d0c7a501c718%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=El+Bols%C3%B3n%2C+R%C3%ADo+Negro%2C+Argentina&is_ski_area=&checkin_year=&checkin_month=&checkout_year=&checkout_month=&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&ss_raw=el+bols&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=es&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=-985282&dest_type=city&place_id_lat=-41.964452&place_id_lon=-71.532732&search_pageview_id=06d48fb6823e00e9&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=06d48fb6823e00e9&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0');
      await page.waitForSelector('.sr_item');
      page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

      console.log('Retrieving hotels data');

      const hoteles = page.evaluate(() => {
        let hoteles = [];
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('sr_item');
        hoteles.push(x);

        let navigation = document.getElementsByClassName('sr_pagination_item');

        for (const nav of navigation) {
          nav.click();
          hoteles.push(document.getElementsByClassName('sr_item'));
        }

        console.log('Finished looping through');

        return hoteles;
      });

    } catch(e) {
      console.log('error', e);
    }
  })();
};
```

So, what I want is to be able to send a GET request from my app and get a response from my API with a list of hotels from booking, it's just a personal project, the thing is, using Postman I'm sending the GET request but I get no response at all, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and what direction to follow, if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The block `({})()` runs your code instantly instead of on a request.
- [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) is a function, you should not reassign this.

Instead, move the function somewhere else and call it like below,

```
async function scraper() {
    try {

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.goto('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.es-ar.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAyIAQGYASy4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgM&lang=es-ar&sid=bc11c3e819d105b3c501d0c7a501c718&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.es-ar.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaAyIAQGYASy4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgM%3Bsid%3Dbc11c3e819d105b3c501d0c7a501c718%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=El+Bols%C3%B3n%2C+R%C3%ADo+Negro%2C+Argentina&is_ski_area=&checkin_year=&checkin_month=&checkout_year=&checkout_month=&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&ss_raw=el+bols&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=es&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=-985282&dest_type=city&place_id_lat=-41.964452&place_id_lon=-71.532732&search_pageview_id=06d48fb6823e00e9&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=06d48fb6823e00e9&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0');
      await page.waitForSelector('.sr_item');
      page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

      console.log('Retrieving hotels data');

      const hoteles = page.evaluate(() => {
        let hoteles = [];
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('sr_item');
        hoteles.push(x);

        let navigation = document.getElementsByClassName('sr_pagination_item');

        for (const nav of navigation) {
          nav.click();
          hoteles.push(document.getElementsByClassName('sr_item'));
        }

        console.log('Finished looping through');

        return hoteles;
      });

    } catch(e) {
      console.log('error', e);
    }
  }

// Call the scraper
exports.get_booking = async (req, res, next) => {
  const scraperData = await scraper();
  res.json(scraperData)
}
```

It will make the controller into a promise and return the JSON data.